# Installing package on R gives compilation error

Tags: r

I'm trying to install HiddenMarkov_1.3-1 on R-2.12.2 and I get the following compilation error. Any ideas?

```
$ R CMD INSTALL HiddenMarkov_1.3-1.tar.gz
* installing to library ‘/R/library’
* installing *source* package ‘HiddenMarkov’ ...
** libs
g77   -fpic  -O3 -c dthmm.f -o dthmm.o
g77   -fpic  -O3 -c extract.f -o extract.o
extract.f: In subroutine `getrow':
extract.f:1: 
     subroutine getrow(m, n, k, a, b)
                          1
e

xtract.f:5: (continued):
         double precision a(n,m), b(m)
                            2
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `n' at (2) [initially seen at (1)]
extract.f:1: 
     subroutine getrow(m, n, k, a, b)
                       1
extract.f:5: (continued):
         double precision a(n,m), b(m)
                              2
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `m' at (2) [initially seen at (1)]
extract.f:1: 
         subroutine getrow(m, n, k, a, b)
                           1
extract.f:6: (continued):
         integer m, n, j, k
                 2
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `m' at (2) [initially seen at (1)]
extract.f:1: 
         subroutine getrow(m, n, k, a, b)
                              1
extract.f:6: (continued):
         integer m, n, j, k
                    2
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `n' at (2) [initially seen at (1)]
extract.f:1: 
         subroutine getrow(m, n, k, a, b)
                                    1
extract.f:7: (continued):
         j = 1
         2
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `a' at (2) [initially seen at (1)]
extract.f:1: 
         subroutine getrow(m, n, k, a, b)
                                       1
extract.f:7: (continued):
         j = 1
         2
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `b' at (2) [initially seen at (1)]
extract.f: In subroutine `getmat':
extract.f:15: 
         subroutine getmat(m, n, k, a, b)
                              1
extract.f:19: (continued):
         double precision a(n,m,m), b(m,m)
                            2
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `n' at (2) [initially seen at (1)]
extract.f:15: 
         subroutine getmat(m, n, k, a, b)
                           1
extract.f:19: (continued):
         double precision a(n,m,m), b(m,m)
                              2
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `m' at (2) [initially seen at (1)]
extract.f:15: 
         subroutine getmat(m, n, k, a, b)
                           1
extract.f:20: (continued):
         integer i, j, k, m, n
                          2
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `m' at (2) [initially seen at (1)]
extract.f:15: 
         subroutine getmat(m, n, k, a, b)
                              1
extract.f:20: (continued):
         integer i, j, k, m, n
                             2
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `n' at (2) [initially seen at (1)]
extract.f:15: 
         subroutine getmat(m, n, k, a, b)
                                    1
extract.f:21: (continued):
         i = 1
         2
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `a' at (2) [initially seen at (1)]
extract.f:15: 
         subroutine getmat(m, n, k, a, b)
                                       1
extract.f:21: (continued):
         i = 1
         2
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `b' at (2) [initially seen at (1)]
make: *** [extract.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘HiddenMarkov’
* removing ‘/R/library/HiddenMarkov’
```

Comment: According to http://cran.github.io/w/r/r2122/search/?q=hiddenmarkov HiddenMarkov 1.4-3 was the current when R 2.12.2 was released, so maybe you can try installing that first. If that does not work, then you probably want to include your gcc/gfortran version number and your OS in the question.

Comment: It was the gfortran compiler. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Gabor Csardi there was an incompatibility between HiddenMarkov 1.4-3 and the gfortran compiler.